# How to create a database from shell command in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, shell, command-line, command

I'm looking for something like createdb in PostgreSQL or any other solution that would allow me to create database with a help of a shell command. Any hints?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

```
cat filename.sql | mysql -u username -p # type mysql password when asked for it
```

Where filename.sql holds all the sql to create your database. Or...

```
echo "create database `database-name`" | mysql -u username -p
```

If you really only want to create a database.

Comment: I get this error ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 27: No database selected
when I run echo "create database databasename" | mysql -u -u username -p command

Comment: @keerthi: perhaps your user doesn't have privileges on any existing schema?

Comment: It's because there are two `-u` flags

Comment: @Kris Can I read database name from terminal and use the variable value as database name  in create database.

Comment: @Clifford: you could using simple (ba)sh script using normal shell arguments. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23563043/shell-script-arguments) Probably merits its own question.

Comment: @Kris Thank you for your help.My problem is something different.

Comment: @Felix Kling's answer is the better one and most directly answers the question.  I could not get this to work because my `.sql` file (straight from a `mysqldump`) didn't contain a command to create the database, and the database itself didn't already exist.

Comment: ```echo "create database \`database-name\`" | mysql -u username -p```

(escape with \\)

Answer (score 256):

You mean while the mysql environment?

```
create database testdb;
```

Or directly from command line:

```
mysql -u root -e "create database testdb";
```

Comment: mysql -u root -e "create database testdb"; 

Thats what i was looking for :) 
thank you

Comment: In case you have password, just add -p. After pressing enter, you will be asked your password. The following is an example using my user which is root (change it if you have anoter username) and it also uses the name "oc_local" for the database (change it if you want your database to be called in a different way)------> mysql -u root -p -e "create database oc_local";

Comment: hi @koszikot -- if this is what you were looking for, you should accept it as the correct answer :-)

Comment: I like to know what the command line options do, for others -e is the short-form for --execute=statement. Find command line options here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html

Comment: the semicolon should be inside quotes

Answer (score 79):

If you create a new database it's good to create user with permissions only for this database (if anything goes wrong you won't compromise root user login and password). So everything together will look like this:

```
mysql -u base_user -pbase_user_pass -e "create database new_db; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON new_db.* TO new_db_user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'new_db_user_pass'"
```

Where:
**base_user** is the name for user with all privileges (probably the root)
**base_user_pass** it's the password for base_user (lack of space between -p and base_user_pass is important)
**new_db** is name for newly created database
**new_db_user** is name for the new user with access only for new_db
**new_db_user_pass** it's the password for new_db_user

Comment: Massive.  Just added this great one liner to dashdocs snippets.  In case anyone has a root password with spaces: `-p"root password here"` works fine

Answer (score 44):

```
mysqladmin -u$USER -p$PASSWORD create $DB_NAME
```

Replace above variables and you are good to go with this oneliner.
$USER is the username, $PASSWORD is the password and $DB_NAME is the name of the database.

Comment: came back to this question many years later and noticed I'd upvoted it :D

Comment: i keep coming back here...

Answer (score 24):

Use

```
$ mysqladmin -u <db_user_name> -p create <db_name>
```

You will be prompted for password. Also make sure the mysql user you use has privileges to create database.

Answer (score 13):

The ist and 2nd answer are good but if anybody is looking for having  a script or  If you want dynamic i.e (db/username/password in variable) then here:

```
#!/bin/bash



DB="mydb"
USER="user1"
PASS="pass_bla"

mysql -uroot -prootpassword -e "CREATE DATABASE $DB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
mysql -uroot -prootpassword -e "CREATE USER $USER@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY '$PASS'";
mysql -uroot -prootpassword -e "GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON $DB.* TO '$USER'@'127.0.0.1'";
```

Comment: This will fail if you include any `.`

Answer (score 11):

You can use [SQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-database.html) on the command line:

```
echo 'CREATE DATABASE dbname;' | mysql <...>
```

Or you can use [`mysqladmin`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqladmin.html):

```
mysqladmin create dbname
```

Answer (score 2):

Connect to DB using base user:

  `mysql -u base_user -pbase_user_pass`

And execute CREATE DATABASE, CREATE USER and GRANT PRIVILEGES Statements.

Here's handy web wizard to help you with statements
[www.bugaco.com/helpers/create_database.html](http://www.bugaco.com/helpers/create_database.html)

Answer (score 0):

For example, after login, you can create `apple` database as shown below:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE apple;
```

And, before login, you can create `apple` database as shown below. *`CREATE ...` with `""` and without `;` is also available:

```
mysql -u root -p -e 'CREATE DATABASE apple;'
```

Or:

```
mysql -u root -p --execute='CREATE DATABASE apple;'
```