# Shell script arguments

Tags: unix

I just started writing shell scripts in Unix so, I am a total newbie

I want to read the arguments given when the user run the script
ex:

```
sh script -a abc
```

I want to read for argument `-a` user gave `abc`.

My code so far:

```
if ( $1 = "-a" )
then var=$2
fi
echo $var
```

I get an error.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: script: 1: script: -a: not found

Comment: Use square brackets instead of parenthesis: `if [ $1 = "-a" ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash uses an external program called [test](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test) to perform boolean tests, but that program is used mostly via its alias `[`.

```
if ( $1 = "-a" )
```

should become

```
if [ $1 = "-a" ]
```

if you use `[` or

```
if test $1 = "-a"
```

Comment: I had no idea that's what `[]` was actually doing +1

Comment: I think many people don't realize that `[` is in fact an executable.  Not sure and not able to test it right away, but Bash has an extended/enhanced/improved test, `[[` which I think is built-in.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $1 = "-a" ]; then
    var=$2
fi
echo $var
```

You shoud be careful of the space between if and `[`