# Is there a way to copy all the data in a mysql database to another? (phpmyadmin)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to copy all the tables, fields, and data from my local server mysql to my hosting sites mysql. Is there a way to copy all the data? (It's only 26kb, very small)

Answer (score 6):

In phpMyAdmin, just export a dump (using the `export`) tab and re-import it on the other server using the `sql` tab.

Make sure you compare the results, I have had phpMyAdmin screw up the import more than once.

If you have shell access to both servers, a combination of

```
mysqldump -u username -p databasename > dump.sql
```

and a

```
mysql -u username -p databasename < dump.sql
```

on the target server is the much more fast and reliable alternative in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at

[Copying MySQL Databases to Another Machine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/copying-databases.html)

[Copy MySQL database from one server to another remote server](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-copy-mysql-database-remote-server.html)

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the following steps:

1. Create the target database using MySQLAdmin or your preferred method. In this example, db2 is the target database, where the source database db1 will be copied.
2. Execute the following statement on a command line:

> mysqldump -h [server] -u [user] -p[password] db1 | mysql -h [server]
>   -u [user] -p[password] db2

Note: There is NO space between -p and [password]

I copied this from [Copy/duplicate database without using mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794/mysql-copy-duplicate-database).
It works fine. Please ensure that you are not inside mysql while running this command.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same version of mysql on both systems (or versions with compatible db file sytsem), you may just copy the data files directly. Usually files are kept in /var/lib/mysql/ on unix systems.

Comment: You should stop the server before doing this, though, as far as I know.

Comment: yes, stop or exec

   "flush tables with read lock"

to flush all data onto disk and prevent any new writes