# Auto and Keep Sync Tool for Two MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization, server, replication

I know there exist many tools to sync two MySQL databases like

- MySQL Workbench
- SQLog
- DataSync
- MySQL Replica not a tool but MySQL build-in Feature

and many of others. What I want to know is

**Is there exist any technique or tool to do real-time Sync? (Keep sync whenever any value changed in any of table)**

Comment: If someone want to know why I want to achieve this. Answer: I did real-time sync for my local directory to my server via FTP. Now If I did same for MySQL then actually my localhost will become live worldwide and my work will be published instantly.

Comment: just check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139197/how-to-keep-two-mysql-databases-in-sync). meet your answer.

Comment: @virendra I guess it can sync but can't do it real time sync.