# How can I insert MySQL remote database table into local database table?

Tags: php, mysql, linux

**Remote Server Database (IP: 192.168.1.19)**

> Database Name : `RemoteDB`
>
> Table Name        : `RemoteTable`

**Local Server Database (IP: 192.168.1.35)**

> Database Name : `LocalDB`
>
> Table Name        : `LocalTable`

**MySQL Query**

```
INSERT INTO LocalDB.LocalTable SELECT * FROM RemoteDB.RemoteTable
```

**But**, This query is not executing, Because of different database connection.

How can I execute this query from local server (**IP: 192.168.1.35**)? Or any linux shell command?

Comment: Use `mysqldump` to dump a schema (create new schema and copy your table to that schema if you dont want to dump everything). Then you can work on the same database.

Comment: why would you do this? just create a dump, and insert this on your local system

Comment: Because, After every 30 minutes I need `RemoteDB.RemoteTable` data into `LocalDB.LocalTable` @LuciaAngermüller

Comment: I don't want to work on same database. :( @PEMapModder

Comment: @SumonSarker i still got no idea why you need to do this? there should be no reason to do sth like this

Comment: Since you tagged this question [php], you might just want to download SELECT * and upload them with INSERT directly using PHP, since you know the database structure.

Comment: Because 2 different projects using same table on different host. @LuciaAngermüller

Comment: Yes! Remote Database is connected and OK @Aniket

Comment: I don't want to fetch result from Remote Table into a PHP variable and Save it to Local Table. I just want to Copy it directly via SQL Query. Because `RemoteDB.RemoteTable` has huge number of rows. Minimum `200MB`. Your solution is not efficient. @Aniket

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127259/discussion-between-sumon-sarker-and-aniket).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysqldump -uRemoteusername -pRemotepassword -h192.168.1.19 RemoteDB RemoteTable  --set-gtid-purged=OFF  | mysql -h192.168.1.35 -uLocalname -pLocalpassword   LocalDB
```

Comment: I fixed the remote server configuration. And now Your answer is working for me. :) Thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

your question is to insert data from different database using php,isnt?

if you want to synconize them you can read this [How to keep two MySQL databases in sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139197/how-to-keep-two-mysql-databases-in-sync)

insert db using php from multiple db is simple

```
$conn1= mysqli_connect($host1,$user1,$pass1);
mysqli_select_db($db1,$conn1);
$conn2= mysqli_connect($host2,$user2,$pass2);
mysqli_select_db($db2,$conn2);

$query=mysql_query("SELECT id,name from tbl_user", $conn1)
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query))
 {
    mysqli_query("insert into tbl_user (id,name) values ('".$row[0]."', '".$row[1]."',$conn2);
 }
```

Comment: I don't want 2 different connection instances. Because remote table have huge number of data. Minimum `6,000,000 rows X 120 columns` :(

Comment: you want to dump or insert? dump (target table must be dropped firstif exists). insert(target table must be exist)

Comment: if your data as big as you said. you must use desktop apps. dont use php. but we still can hack this with limitation select than refresh it with javascript. or maybe using cronjob. (i just brainstorming, because inever doing that using web apps)

Comment: i just found this. maybe can help you http://wesbos.com/import-large-mysql-database-bigdump-php/

Comment: Thank you! But I don't want like this. My problem is now solved!

Comment: Can you anwer by answer yourself thread question please? Just share with us. It can be help aomeone else who have same problem with you

Comment: Ok, I will post my solution. Thank you @plonknimbuzz

Comment: I posted my solution. :) You can review it @plonknimbuzz

Comment: What about if  $row[0]  contains the single quote character. This will not work.

Answer (score 2):

> I converted the approved answer for **CronJob** to my **PHP script** as below -

**Configurations :**

```
$remoteDbUser   = '***';
$remoteDbPass   = '***';
$remoteDbHost   = '192.168.1.19';
$remoteDb       = 'RemoteDB';
#$remoteDbTable = '';
$localDbHost    = '192.168.1.35';
$localDbUser    = '***';
$localDbPass    = '***';
$localDb        = 'LocalDB';
```

**Synchronize function :**

```
/*Passing `$remoteDbTable` name as function argument, Because I have many Remote DB table to synchronize with my Local DB table*/
function RemoteDbSynchronze($remoteDbTable='RemoteTable'){
  global $remoteDbUser,
    $remoteDbPass,
    $remoteDbHost,
    $remoteDb,
    $localDbHost,
    $localDbUser,
    $localDbPass,
    $localDb;
  $sql = sprintf(
    "mysqldump -u%s -p%s -h%s %s %s  --set-gtid-purged=OFF  | mysql -h%s -u%s -p%s %s",
    $remoteDbUser,
    $remoteDbPass,
    $remoteDbHost,
    $remoteDb,
    $remoteDbTable,
    $localDbHost,
    $localDbUser,
    $localDbPass,
    $localDb
  );
  shell_exec($sql);
}
```

**Calling function from Cron script:**

```
RemoteDbSynchronze('RemoteTable');
RemoteDbSynchronze('AnotherRemoteTable1');
RemoteDbSynchronze('AnotherRemoteTable2');
..........................................
RemoteDbSynchronze('AnotherRemoteTableN');
```

> More details about [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf) , [shell_exec](http://php.net/shell_exec) and [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: thank bro for sharing. it might be helfull for me or  others sometimes later