# Need insight into script to copy InnoDB tables to another database

Tags: mysql, scripting

I have a mysql database with InnoDB tables that I need to copy into a newly created database. I would like to automate the copying process with a script since there are over 100 tables.

This is my current code. After 10 tables, it's getting tiresome:

```
> use newdb; 
> CREATE TABLE tableA LIKE old_db.tableA
> INSERT INTO tableA SELECT * FROM old_db.tableA
```

How can I extract the table names from `old_db` in order to automate this process?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1995186/3450424 seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MySQLWorkbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to export the schema and data from the source database and then import into the new database.