# How to clone a mysql database using shell and terminal without taking mysql dump and uploading

Tags: php, mysql, shell, terminal

Is there any way to clone a mysql database in linux/windows server without taking dump and import it again to another db.

If there is a solution please give me the answer.

Comment: maybe import the physical data from server a to server b -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/copying-databases.html

Comment: I dont understand can you please brief more.

Comment: added in my comment before the link to mysql documentation

Comment: [link for your solution][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794/mysql-copy-duplicate-database

hope will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked perfectly for my requirement

```
mysqldump -h [server] -u [user] -p[password] db1 | mysql -h [server] -u [user] -p[password] db2
```