# How to batch export tables to separate files in Phpmyadmin or via mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database that consists of 50 tables. I need each table exported as separate file. 1 table → 1 export file. However, I do not like to export-click through all 50 tables in the phpmyadmin export dialog to generate those single export files.

Is there any option in Phpmyadmin to have each table separately exported as file?

**Only if not**, how would you do this via SSH/mysqldump as workaround (iterating over all tables)? I only found a [way here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/9306) of specifying each single table by name.

*PS: In case somebody wants to know why I need this, I tried running a mysql import of a 0.5 GB file which throws errors and I cannot track them down. Importing table by table would help to find the problem.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL copy/duplicate database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794/mysql-copy-duplicate-database)

Comment: My primary goal is to do it via Phpmyadmin. The linked "duplicate" talks about "MySQL copy/duplicate database" which is in no way the core of my question.

Comment: Whilst that maybe true, phpmyadmin in practice is hardly suited for this task as you have already found out and is the reason for this question. Another factor work mentioning is that you would need to deal with script timeouts and providing sufficient permissions for the web account to carry out these tasks.

Comment: If it's your phpmyadmin, then you also have access via the mysql command line. do the import there so you can see what the raw errors/notices are.