# How would I have my database backed up nightly to another server?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'd like to be able to backup my database files from one phpmyadmin server to another, every night.  I know it is possible to copy/duplicate using something similiar to : 
 mysqldump -h [server] -u [user] -p[password] db1 | mysql -h [server] -u [user] -p[password] db2   
( I found this in the comments of the following:  [Copy/duplicate database without using mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794/copy-duplicate-database-without-using-mysqldump) ) 
Though I do not know how I would automatically do this.  If anyone could give me an answer or some tips, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=mysqldump+backup+to+different+server

Comment: That shows something similar to what I said and linked, but how would I have it happen automatically?  Say at like 5 am everyday?

Comment: Cronjob, task planer, ...?

Comment: I just started learning about cron yesterday but would the following work? <br> * 5 * * * root run-parts /etc/daily.backup  <br> and in that folder have a file containing my code from above?

Comment: You asked specifically about using phpMyAdmin for this project, which basically can't be done — phpMyAdmin is a graphical interface designed to be used interactively. There are plenty of scriptable tools, such as `mysqldump`, which you also asked about and does the job better than phpMyAdmin in cases like this because you can schedule it and don't have to click around manually.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation on how to get the scheduling done of when mysqldump runs?